# Drawing with a Graphics object stops working after re-using it several thousand times

Tags: c#, graphics, windows-ce, gdi

I'm developing a user control that uses a `PictureBox` to draw a graph on a Windows CE device using Visual Studio 2008 and `System.Graphics`.

My initial code to draw on the PictureBox was this:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(picturebox1.CreateGraphics().GetHdc());
```

But it had a bad performance, so I used a global variable `Graphics g` and changed my code to this:

```
g = g ?? Graphics.FromHdc(picturebox1.CreateGraphics().GetHdc());
```

Then I have a weird problem! I have a timer in my code that draws dots on the `PictureBox`, after using `Graphics` for about 22,000 times, it stops drawing, although the code is still running. Then when I put a break point on the line of code I wrote above and using QuickWatch to forcely renew the graphic object like this:

```
 g = Graphics.FromHdc(picturebox1.CreateGraphics().GetHdc());
```

It starts to continue drawing and won't stop again. I even changed my code so it creates a new object after 22,000 times, but this new object also stopped working after another 22,000 times of using the `Graphics` object.

Comment: Don't use a global for something that isn't globally relevant.. (even then make sure there isn't an alternative)... You should revert back to the original and see what is causing the "bad performance", my guess is your not disposing the [Graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx), its IDisposable

Comment: `picturebox1.CreateGraphics()` returns a `Graphics` object. Why are you not using that and creating another from `Graphics.FromHdc` ?

Comment: Thanks Sriram Sakthivel ,It worked ! in windows CE some of the common methods are not exist , I thought picturebox does not have CreateGraphics(). Put your comment in Answers plz.

Comment: @Navid While that works, please read my answer - actively drawing using `CreateGraphics` interferes with the control's standard drawing and may lead to unexpected results (i.e. you may not see what you should see).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not a good idea to actively draw into a control like you do. Try to create a subclass of `PictureBox` (or if you don't need the other `PictureBox` functionality, subclass from `Panel` or even `Control`) and override the paint events that will be called by the system if drawing is necessary. If you need to redraw, call `Invalidate` on the control. The reason to do so is you don't have to handle all the `Graphics` creation, as this will be done for you and also your drawing doesn't interfere with the default drawing of the control.

Another approach would be to draw into a `Bitmap` and set it as the `PictureBox` image (which may be slower than desired).

Comment: Creating a custom control (using the standard Visual Studio project item template) would be another option besides `Panel`, if no standard functionality besides painting is required. The template by default includes code to override the `OnPaint` method. That method receives a `Graphics` object via its `PaintEventArgs e` parameter. That way there's no need to acquire/release it manually. Of course `OnPaint` can also be overridden with `Panel` or `PictureBox`.

Comment: Thanks, @stakx, I changed my answer a bit to account for custom control creation instead of subclassing the higher-level `Panel`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to Release and Dispose the object every time to avoid that problem

like :

```
 // Release handle to device context and dispose of the Graphics object
e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
newGraphics.Dispose();
```

Comment: Well, he said he only created it once, so he only needs to delete it once.